# Why NumPy: np.fill_diagonal() changes the diagnoal values of all related variables?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Dear experienced friends, I met a question when I was trying to use the `np.fill_diagonal()`. Firstly I set two sub-variables from an original NumPy array. Then I used `np.fill_diagonal()` to change the diagonal values of one of the variables. However, I found all variables' diagonal values have been changed.

May I ask why this happened? Are all the related NumPy variables share the same memory? And how can I know their exact memory relationship? Thank you!

Here is the simple code:

```
# we set the original one
a = np.array([[    10., 1., 1., 1.,  1.],
        [2.,  20., 140.,  8.,   57.],
        [3.,  3.,  30.,   21.,  51.],
        [4.,  4.,  21.,   40.,  56.],
        [5.,  5.,  31.,  16.,   50.]])

# the two sub-variables
b1 = a[:5,:5]
b2 = a[:5,:5]

# then I change the diagonal value of one of the sub-variables
np.fill_diagonal(b1, 0)
```

We are supposed to only change the value of `b1`, but actually all `a`, `b1`, and `b2` are changed. May I ask how can I change the diagonal value of `b1` only but not affect others? Thank you!

```
a

array([[  0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  2.,   0., 140.,   8.,  57.],
       [  3.,   3.,   0.,  21.,  51.],
       [  4.,   4.,  21.,   0.,  56.],
       [  5.,   5.,  31.,  16.,   0.]])

b2

array([[  0.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  2.,   0., 140.,   8.,  57.],
       [  3.,   3.,   0.,  21.,  51.],
       [  4.,   4.,  21.,   0.,  56.],
       [  5.,   5.,  31.,  16.,   0.]])
```

Comment: copy the underlying data: `b1 = a[:5, :5].copy()`.

Comment: Thank you Hoang. It works. May I ask why this happened? Are all the related NumPy variables share the same memory? And how can I know their exact memory relationship?

Comment: See the note under `Basic Slicing and Indexing` in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

Comment: Thank you Hoang. This is exactly what I need! (I just copy it here for people's future reference) NumPy slicing creates a view instead of a copy as in the case of builtin Python sequences such as string, tuple and list. Care must be taken when extracting a small portion from a large array which becomes useless after the extraction, because the small portion extracted contains a reference to the large original array whose memory will not be released until all arrays derived from it are garbage-collected. In such cases an explicit copy() is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like b1 and b2 are just references to a. Try using numpy.copy() and then preforming the splicing to get a "deep copy" so that b1 and b2 have their own spaces in memory. check out numpy.copy in the [Numpy API documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html).